# How to indent macros in this manner using a beautifier?

Tags: clang, clang-format

I want my preprocessors to be indented in this manner:

```
int foo_func()
{
    normal_code();
    normal_code();
#ifdef FOO
#  define aaa
#  define bbb
    code_that_only_foo();
    code_that_only_foo();
#endif
    normal_code_again();
    normal_code_again();
}
```

I have tried *clang-format*, but it removes all spaces after `#` directive, and I failed to find any option to control that behavior. So,  Could clang-format perform preprocessor indentation in that way?

Comment: You say "good manner"; I say "ew"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Modified

Comment: I don't think it exist. Just fork the beautifer you love and do it yourself, since it's not a well-known indentation.

Comment: @jiandingzhe: also, are you aware that the question, formed in that way, is at the moment off-topic? *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Excellent. So when I this problem, where can I ask such kind of questions?

Comment: @jiandingzhe: instead of asking *is there any tool that does it*, I'd ask *how can I do it?*. This way, "homemade" solutions are not discriminated.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Modified. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find a tool that does the job, write a tool that does:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sys import stdin
from string import whitespace


def main():
    not_directive = whitespace + '#'
    indentation = 0
    for line in stdin:
        stripped = line.lstrip()
        if stripped.startswith('#'):
            directive = stripped.lstrip(not_directive)
            if directive.startswith('endif'):
                indentation -= 1
            print('#{}{}'.format('  ' * indentation, directive), end='')
            if directive.startswith('if'):
                indentation += 1
        else:
            print(line, end='')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[See it working online](http://rextester.com/LWU64861)

It reads the source from the stdin, and writes changed source to the stdout.
You can easily redirect input and output with shell.

If you don't know Python3 and wish to understand it:

- *`string`*`.lstrip(`*`chars`*`)` returns *`string`* with *`chars`* removed from it's beggining.
  *`chars`* defaults to *`whitespace`*.
- `'test' * 0` => `''`, `'test' * 1` => `'test'`, `'test' * 3` => `'testtesttest'`
- `'#{}{}'.format('textA', 'textB')` => `'#textAtextB'`